How to display /image/jpeg.cgi in Chrome and Opera? (with html)
I own a D-Link webcam and I want to display a snapshot in a browser:
<img src ="http://guest:1234@my-ip/image/jpeg.cgi">

but the image is only displayed in Firefox. In Chrome and on Android in Opera there is only the placeholder.
If I right click right and click "open image in a new window" it is opened in an new window.
Is there any possibility to display the image directly (i.e. by a php-script?) in the html-site?
Also tried
<img src ="http://guest:1234@my-ip/image/jpeg.cgi?profileid=1">


Does the request succeed? Are there any error in the console? What is the mime type?

When I enter "http://guest:1234@my-ip/image/jpeg.cgi" in Chrome-Browser on Windows the Image is displayed. When I write it on my webpage in html <img scr="... no picture is displayed. (in Kodi-favourite it works by the way)

Thanks for your comment, but you're basically just repeating what you said in the original post. That doesn't answer any of the sensible questions Shingo asked you. Use developer tools in the various browsers to investigate further and reply to those enquiries. We need to understand the precise technical nature of the fault in order to start suggesting any potential solutions.

Also tried <img src ="<img src ="http...this makes absolutely zero sense whatsoever, I don't know why you expected that it was even worth trying?! The src of an image has to be a valid HTTP(s) URL or data-URL. Putting another img tag inside that is just gibberish. Try to base your attempted solutions on research, observable facts, and results of your investigations, rather than random guesswork.

Also...what does any of this have to do with PHP code?? Reminder: [ask], and What are tags, and how should I use them?

It seems to be a special problem with the D-Link Camera and Chrome; it is not for me but for anyone (webcam) who has any browser! I did try php, java script and html commands like <embed scr... but nothing works on Chrome or Opera. Looking here for a real specialist who can say what Chrome makes different than Firefox and might write a script that displays the image in the same window (a Link to click like Webcampicture works but one would have to click the link before Image is displayed and it will not be displayed in the same frame.

We can give you specialist help if, as requested twice already, you provide some useful information from debugging the image request using your browser's console and network tools. We can't access the IP you're trying to reach, so that's your job. Nor do we necessarily possess the particular piece of hardware to test it ourselves. If you want our help, provide some technical info as request. Is there any specific reason why you haven't done that yet? Do you understand what we're asking you to do?

I am no specialist for browser console (I only use Windows) and of course you can not access a D-Link-cam but I would try any suggested html, php, java script or pearl script I could run on my homepage and report the result here but I fear there is no way to display the image in between any code in Chrome or Opera as the linking of the image always has to be with the <img src="... command what not works in Chrome and Opera. :(

I have no idea what you are trying to say, sorry. You don't need to be a "specialist" in order to look at your browser's console and check for errors. This is basic web debugging which any web developer should be comfortable with. Whether you use Windows or another O/S is not relevant - the browser tools are part of the browser, not the O/S. And most of the major browser vendors supply very similar-looking tools, so once you've used the tools in Chrome you can use the tools in Firefox, Opera etc very easily as well.

Just open a new empty tab, then hit F12 (in most browsers, or you can find it in the menu) to open the developer tools. Then load the web page which is giving you the trouble into that new tab. Now look again at the tools. Are there any errors in the Console area which seem to relate to the image? What about in the Network tool - there should be a record of the HTTP request to the http://guest:1234@my-ip/image/jpeg.cgi URL (i.e. the attempt to load the image into the img tag) - what HTTP status code does that request return? Click into it...what was the raw response content?

...and you can compare what happens in the browser which works, to what happens in the browser which doesn't, and see if there any differences in terms of any error messages generated, any difference in the HTTP response etc. If we can see the scenario in this way from a technical point of view, we may be able to start to understand what is happening, and maybe identify why the image won't load it certain browsers / situations.

When I type F12 and enter http://guest:1234@my-ip/image/jpeg.cgi the jpeg.cgi is displayed as picture on the left and as binary ... in the F12-Windows.  But when I enter the html page with the  
command jpeg.cgi is not displayed and no binary content and not even the name jpeg.cgi in the "F12-site" window what means nothing in the img-command is loaded. Console is empty and no error reported.

I tried to download the image what does not work as the camera works on port 80 what is not secure and therefore blocked by Chorome. :( Changing camera port to 443 in the camera setup and setting html to <img src="https://.... also does not display the image. Isn't it possible to simulate a save picture in Chrome on port 80 by html commands what might help? The rights for the website in Chrome already are set to "admit unsecure content" by me what also did not help. Download of the pic by rightclick now says network error :-0

Changing camera port to 443 in the camera setup and setting html to <img src="https://.... also does not display the image...ok, so what happens in the console and network tool in that scenario? At minimum you will see the request to the CGI script appearing in the Network tool (but you must open the network tool before you load the page, otherwise it won't show up). Tell us what HTTP response code you get to that request in Chrome, compared to what you see in Firefox for the same request. [edit] your question to show all relevant info - important details don't belong buried in comments

With port 443 I get the same result as on port 80: No message in the console,no message in "problems", no displayed jpeg.cgi in F12-window. I'm still not sure whether it is https problem at all. I do not know nothing about jpeg.cgi format (normal jpg?). In any case as I am not able to modify the browser as it should deliver access to anyone with any browser and I am not able to change the firmware of the camera I really would need a page-script here to try to display the embedded image. (in all variations jpeg.cgi does not appear in the F12 window! except direct query string access of course)

I don't see how it's possible that you are not seeing the jpeg.cgi in the Network window. This is what happens when I copy your HTML and run it locally in my testing server: https://imgur.com/a/1RiB2cX . In those images I show you the code, the page I loaded into the Chrome browser, and the details I see in the Network tool. The request to the image fails of course because I do not have the camera available, but the point is that it is definitely visible. It must be visible for you too. Either a) you are looking in the wrong place or b) something that you haven't shown us here is blocking it

I also don't see how it's possible that the html img src command does not load the jpeg.cgi . I think I will use an other camera. If I save the jpeg.cgi lokal it is loaded by the  but not from the camera :( .As even php uses the echo <img src... command and also html embed tag does not work it will remain unsolvable unless anyone with the same D-Link DCS-935L did solve the problem for Chrome and Opera with a special unknown image display command...

The browser doesn't care where the image URL came from. It doesn't know it's from a camera or anything else. It just tries to send a HTTP request, and get a response. Using your browser's Network tool you can trace what happened to that HTTP request, like I showed you in my pictures. You still haven't told me precisely what you saw in your Network tool when you tried that yourself.

I do not have any Network tool and do not know how the request is made internally in Chrome but as jpeg.cgi does not appear in the F12 window it is not done for unknown reason. There is a working solution for me in using "; ?> (but my provider wants money for copying from external url in php...)

I do not have any Network tool...yes you do. Every browser has this. It's within the F12 tools. Did you actually look at the screenshots I provided in https://imgur.com/a/1RiB2cX ? You can see that within the F12 tools there is Elements, Console, Sources, Network etc etc. That is where you find the Network tool. Perhaps if your browser has a different language setting it may be named differently, but it's definitely there.

I do not see how to debug Chrome with F12 tool to find out why Chrome doesn't load the image.As mentioned it would not help as I cann not provide an own Chrome/Opera version.Fact is camera-jpeg.cgi in any img html command is not loaded in these browsers. If copied to an image with php it works (only solution in moment).I will no further comment debugging suggestions as this doesn't help.But I would apreciate suggestions in java script or html or any other suggestions. Meanwhile I take an other provider where php copying is for free (or use the other camera; not yet decided). Thanks anyway!

I do not see how to debug Chrome with F12 tool to find out why Chrome doesn't load the image...you do it exactly as I showed in my pictures. That was using Chrome.

Fact is camera-jpeg.cgi in any img html command is not loaded in these browsers...I know.  We've been trying to find out why. But you seemingly don't want to do the relevant investigation, for reasons which completely escape me. You claim you cannot see the network developer tool...but this is not possible - all browsers have this tool. Debugging is the only way you will solve this. "is not loaded" isn't a solvable error message. If you don't want to do any more debugging then you won't solve your problem.

I tried to help you, but it seems you do not actually want to be helped, you want some sort of (non-existent) magic instead. Good luck with that.

But I would apreciate suggestions in java script or html or any other suggestions...it's not possible to make suggestions while we do not really know what the root cause of "is not loaded" is. For as long as you refuse to properly use the browser's tools to look at the HTTP request (and this may possibly be only the first step in the process, we don't know for sure yet), this will remain the case. I cann not provide an own Chrome/Opera version...I have no idea what this is supposed to mean, or how you think it's relevant, sorry.

I think you do not understand what I need. I need a script that shows (unblocks) the blocked image in any(!) browser (whatever the reason for blocking it in Chrome and Opera might be). Perhaps any other user might help one day with a sample script one day (except in copying it in php what works too).

whatever the reason...unless we know the reason why it's blocked, how can anyone provide something which unblocks it? It would just be guesswork. It's like asking us for a tool to "fix the plumbing" when we have no idea what the actual fault is. Apply a bit of logic to what you're asking, please. I don't know why you don't simply provide the information I asked for over a week ago, instead of spending time making spurious arguments about why that isn't necessary. I don't see a long line of people here coming forward with solutions. There might be a reason for that.

There is no reason mentioned for blocking the cam-url in Chrome (F12 window remains empty for that). I have been playing with Java script a while without success. The only way it works is to copy it as mentioned with php on an other server whrer php copy command from external urls is provided (what makes be dependent from two different free providers, but as long as it works it is the only way to solve the problem for me at the moment...).

F12 window remains empty for that...I proved that's not the case and provided images which demonstrate it, when I run the exact same HTML code that you showed us. Your browser isn't any different to mine (unless there's something you haven't mentioned). You must be doing something wrong I think. Did you definitely open the Network tool before you try to load the page which contains the <img tag? Are you definitely looking at the Network area of the F12 tools, and not another part?
